# WPF DataBinding EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datagrid

Could you help me?
I need to binding some data in DataGrid. I have the "lesson" table in MSSQL with "Time_start" datetime column and the DataGrid in my WPF project. How can I binding "Time_start.Date" property to DataGrid.

Now I have some code which doesnt work.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="lessonsGrid" Margin="249,82,32,12">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time_start.Date}" Header="Date" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a `StringFormat` on your binding. Try doing this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="lessonsGrid" Margin="249,82,32,12">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time_start, StringFormat=d}" Header="Date" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), so you know what pattern do you want to use. On my example, I'm using a short date pattern (d).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

If your datacontext has a property called lessons then set the data grid's items source.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="lessonsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding lessons}" Margin="249,82,32,12">
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did it in .cs